# Fixed Height Table in Detail Section of Crystal Report

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, crystal-reports

I M Creating Invoice in Crystal Report with windows form . But i want fixed height table in detail section in Crystal Report. Detail section show blank space , instead i want data inside table of fixed height inside detail section of crystal report.

I M Using Visual Studio 2013 , Sql Server 2012 , CR 13.0.12

Comment: How many records will be present in details section

Comment: minimum one and maximum twenty records

Comment: Ok so there can be at max 20 rows..now to what size you want to limit the details

Comment: Problem Solved - Thanx Siva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use box from page header to page footer .

Comment: Accept it as answer..so that others can use